# Найти все совпадения в таблице и посчитать соответствующую колонку в Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

У меня есть исходная таблица вида

```
место | номер участника | приз ($) | турнир |
```

Там есть данные по различным турнирам. Один участник мог участвовать в нескольких турнирах и занять в них призовые места

Есть таблица, где эти данные нужно обработать

```
номер участника | Кол-во призовых мест (всего)| приз ($) (всего) | средний приз | среднее место
```

Для того, чтобы найти и сложить количество призовых мест у одного участника, я использовала формулу

```
=COUNTIFS('ПОБЕДИТЕЛИ (ВСЕ)'!B2:B; $C2)
```

Возникшие трудности

- С тем, чтобы посчитать еще все призы в сумме - есть проблема, не могу подобрать формулу, которая бы нашла все вхождения по данным из колонки "номер участника" и при этом складывала другую колонку  (приз ($)) в одну цифру, которая соответствует найденному вхождению.
- Также не могу сообразить, как сложить все призовые места в одну
  цифру, чтобы можно было высчитать среднее место. В принципе эта трудность аналогична вышеописанной.

Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Есть идеи, есть... И первая - покажите ссылку на пример таблицы, Вам же помощь нужна. И желательно определиться, где нужно решение. *Excel* и *Google*-таблицы хоть и похожи, но имеют различия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был бы пример, были бы и нормальные формулы. А так - получите наброски.

Для одного участника:

- количество призовых:

  `=COUNTIF(призовые_номера; номер_участника)`
- сумма призов:

  `=SUMIF(призовые_номера; номер_участника; призовые_суммы)`
- средний приз:

  `=сумма_призов_участника/количество_призовых_участника`
- среднее место:

  `=SUMIF(призовые_номера; номер_участника; призовые_места)/к-во_призовых_участника`

Answer (score 0):

В экселе есть возможность сделать сводную таблицу, используйте этот инструмент для создания второй (результирующей) таблицы, он даст Вам возможность легко выполнить эту задачу.